# PHP stdClass How to get an object within an array that's also in an array?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, stdclass

```
Array
 (
    [data] => Array
         (
           [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => name
                [id] => 123
            )

    )
```

I have something like this. I am trying to get the id from within an array of an array... which kinda confuses me.

```
To get the id: echo $array[0]->id;
```

But then how do I get that array from array[data]?

Thanks

Comment: `$array['data'][0]->id;`

Comment: try $array["data"][0]->id

Comment: Want to vote for both of your answers but it only let me vote once. Thank you guys! It was just a silly thing I was missing. :) thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first array is in a var named `$array`.

Your array `$array` contains an other array into the `'data'` key.

So to retrieve this second array you can do this :

```
$second_array = $array['data']; //this will return the second array
```

`$second_array` contains an object into the `0` key. You can retrieve this object, as you said with :

```
$obj = $second_array[0];
```

And then to retrieve the `id` from `$obj`

```
$obj->id;
```

To get the `id` in one line :

```
$array['data'][0]->id; //will return the attr id from the object
```

Comment: do you know whether I need to do it in a foreach loop? I don't quite understand it.

Comment: as @Khushboo said, you don't need a loop to retrieve the object.

Comment: What if there were more id and names, would I need a loop then? And @krichprollsch, thank you so much! Very well explained!!! Thank you for having the patience to explain in such small steps which I am able to understand :)

Comment: You mean if you have more objects into the second array ? it depends what you want to do. But I think yes, you will need a loop. you can do a `foreach ($array['data'] as $obj) { echo $obj->id; }`